# Cannot convert char(*)[50] to char* in assignment

Tags: c++, arrays

Newbie question here...why does the following code only work with a 1D array but not a 2D array? Shouldn't it not make a difference whether b is pointing to the start of a 1D array or a 2D array, as long as it's a char* pointer (as it is)? I thought that the general notation [bound1][bound2] was an equivalent of [bound1*bound2], even over the assignment operation. Help?

```
main() //this works fine 
    {
        char *b;
        b = new char[50];
        return 0;
    }
```

.

```
main() //but this raises the error "Cannot convert char(*)[50] to char* in assignment"
{
    char *b;
    b = new char[50][50];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sometimes it helps if you search SO  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`char[50];` is array of 50 elements of type `char`. Each element has type `char`. So `new char[50];` returns a pointer to first element: `char *` - pointer to `char`.

`char[50][50]` is NOT array of `char`. It is array of arrays. Each element has type `char[50]`. So `new char[50][50];` returns a pointer to first element: `char (*)[50]` - pointer to `char[50]`.

Declare `b` this way:

```
char (*b)[50];
```

Test: http://ideone.com/1zJs1O

Answer (score 0):

If your were right with that [bound1][bound2] and [bound1*bound2] were equivalent you wouldn't have created a 2D array. The size of allocated memory, that's what your multiplication implies, is not the problem here, it's about different data types: A 1D array is simply not a 2D array and that's what the compiler is telling you. You should read about C++ type system and type safety.

[What is type safety and what are the "type safe" alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140369/what-is-type-safety-and-what-are-the-type-safe-alternatives)